# Dynamics CRM gives different available appointments via webservice and UI

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm

We have a service that can be booked either via the Dynamics UI or via a webservice call. It is set for service appointments of 30 min duration starting every 30 mins, with the service start time set to 9:15.

As you would expect, hitting the schedule button in the Dynamics UI offers appointments at 9:15, 9:45, etc.

Sending a "searchrequest" to the webservice for the same service type gets back a list of appointments at 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, etc regardless of the start time set for the service.

How do you make a searchrequest that respects service start times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the anchoroffset property of the service needs to be assigned to the anchoroffset of the search request.